# Converting multiple .dat files with binary data to .csv with same file name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, binary

[image: Error description]I have a folder with .dat files with binary data which I want to parse and write to .csv files with same name as that of .dat files. I could take single .dat file and convert it to its respective .csv to the folder I need.

```
     import numpy as np
     import pandas as pd
     raw_file= '/home/targetfolder/channel1.dat'
     with open(raw_file, "rb") as f:

              raw_data = np.fromstring(f.read(), dtype=np.float32)
              comb_np_array = np.vstack(raw_data)
              big_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)
              big_frame.to_csv("/home/destinationfolder/channel1.csv")

     f.close()
```

Output in ´filename.csv
0,-47.418867
1,-47.443828
2,-47.4445311
3,-47.4738281
4,-47.4193871
5,-47.4222221
6,-47.4193878

Here is the link I followed to do the same : [Python: How to save *.dat-files as *.csv-files to new folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837652/python-how-to-save-dat-files-as-csv-files-to-new-folder)

```
    import csv
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join, splitext

    dat_folder = "/home/nri/"
    csv_folder = "/home/nri/tmp/"

     onlyfilenames = [f for f in listdir(dat_folder) if 
                      isfile(join(dat_folder,f))]
     for fullfilename in onlyfilenames:
          file_name, file_extension = splitext(fullfilename)
          if file_extension == ".dat":
              inputfile=dat_folder + fullfilename
              with open(inputfile, "rb") as f:

                   inputfile = np.fromstring(f.read(), dtype=np.float32)
                   comb_np_array = np.vstack(raw_data)
                   n = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)

             with open(join(csv_folder, file_name + ".csv"), "w", 
                            newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')
                    for row in range(len(n)):
                          writer.writerows(n)
```

But the above gives an error : "sequence expected" . Please let me know how to desired result.

Comment: post the complete traceback, where is the exception coming from (line number?)? Do you have a sample .dat file?

Comment: [link ]https://www.dropbox.com/s/du00e29th219cp1/channel1.dat?dl=0

sample dat file and the error is at last line of code :

writer.writerrows(n)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over len(n) but writing n every time.

```
for row in range(len(n)):
    writer.writerows(n)
```

writerows accepts sequence of sequences, but you are passing a data frame and expecting the writer to iterate on it, but a data frame is not a sequence in your case (python 2?). [Here is how you can check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937114).

```
>>> import collections
>>> isinstance(big_frame, collections.Sequence)
False
```

You will need to [iterate over the data frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and write the cell,

```
for i, row in big_frame.iterrows():
    writer.writerow([i, row[0]]) # 0 is the col name here
```